# How to have degrees Celsius in Conky?

Tags: conky

I have a very simple conky script with the relevant line being:

```
RAM: $memperc% CPU: $cpu%  ${time %a, %d %b}  ${time %H:%M}  C: ${acpitemp}
```

But I want to put the little degree sign before "C" in `C: ${acpitemp}`. How do I do that?

Also, can I have the CPU and RMA to read with two digits? So when the usage is below 10% it would look like `09%` and not just `9%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, you can get that sign for **Character Map** but to make your work easier, here it is

°

For the second part, you can use **$if** loop.I don't think there is an easier method.
You have to add
`$if {{exec sensors |grep 'Core 0' |awk '{print$3+0}'} <10} 0 $endif` after **CPU:**

This will go like this.

```
RAM: $memperc% CPU: $if {{exec sensors |grep 'Core 0' |awk '{print$3+0}'} <10} 0 $endif $cpu%  ${time %a, %d %b}  ${time %H:%M}  C: ${acpitemp}
```

You can cgange it according to your needs

> **NOTE:-** If loop will require you to execute commands, which  take lot CPU power.